# Asyncio: Fastapi with aio-pika, consumer ignores Await

Tags: websocket, async-await, rabbitmq, python-asyncio, fastapi

I am trying to hook my websocket endpoint with rabbitmq (aio-pika). Goal is to have listener in that endpoint and on any new message from queue pass the message to browser client over websockets.

I tested the consumer with asyncio in a script with asyncio loop. Works as I followed and used **aio-pika** documentation. (source: https://aio-pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rabbitmq-tutorial/2-work-queues.html, **worker.py**)

However, when I use it in **fastapi** in websockets endpoint, I cant make it work. Somehow the listener:

```
await queue.consume(on_message)
```

is completely ignored.

This is my attempt (I put it all in one function, so its more readable):

```
@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    print("Entering websockets")
    await manager.connect(websocket)
    print("got connection")

    # params
    queue_name = "task_events"
    routing_key = "user_id.task"


    con = "amqp://rabbitmq:rabbitmq@rabbit:5672/"
    connection = await connect(con)
    channel = await connection.channel()


    await channel.set_qos(prefetch_count=1)

    exchange = await channel.declare_exchange(
        "topic_logs",
        ExchangeType.TOPIC,
    )

    # Declaring queue
    queue = await channel.declare_queue(queue_name)

    # Binding the queue to the exchange
    await queue.bind(exchange, routing_key)

    async def on_message(message: IncomingMessage):
        async with message.process():
            # here will be the message passed over websockets to browser client
            print("sent", message.body)

    

    
    try:
        
        ######### Not working as expected ###########
        # await does not await and websockets finishes, as there is no loop
        await queue.consume(on_message) 
        #############################################

        ################ This Alternative code atleast receives some messages #############
        # If I use this part, I atleast get some messages, when I trigger a backend task that publishes new messages to the queue. 
        # It seems like the messages are somehow stuck and new task releases all stucked messages, but does not release new one. 
        while True: 
            await queue.consume(on_message)
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        ################## one part #############

    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        manager.disconnect(websocket)
```

I am quite new to async in python. I am not sure where is the problem and I cannot somehow implement async consuming loop while getting inspired with worker.py from aio-pika.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simply.

aio-pika queue.consume even though we use await is nonblocking, so
this way we consume

```
consumer_tag = await queue.consume(on_message, no_ack=True)
```

and at the end of connection we cancel

```
await queue.cancel(consumer_tag)
```

The core of the solution for me, was to make something asyncio blocking, so I used
this part of the code after **consume**

```
while True:
    data = await websocket.receive_text()
    x = await manager.send_message(data, websocket)
```

I dont use this code, but its useful as this part of the code waits for frontend websocket response. If this part of the code is missing, then what happens is that client connects just to get disconnected (the websocket endpoit is succefully executed), as there is nothing blocking

Answer (score 1):

You could use an async iterator, which is the second canonical way to consume  messages from a queue.

In your case, this means:

```py
async with queue.iterator() as iter:
  async for message in iter:
    async with message.process():
      # do something with message
```

It will block as long as no message is received and will be suspended again after processing a message.